# Calculate and filter two Integer Fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a models.py file with the following models

```
class Accommodation(models.Model):
...
```

and

```
PERSONS_CHOICE = [(i,str(i)) for i in range(1,9)]
SUPPLEMENTARY_BED = [(i,str(i)) for i in range(1,3)]

class Unit(models.Model):
    accommodation = models.ForeignKey(Accommodation, related_name='accommodation_unit')
    ...
    persons = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=PERSONS_CHOICE)
    supplementary_bed = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=SUPPLEMENTARY_BED, blank=True, null=True)
```

There can be 1 to n Units for an Accommodation and in my views.py I would like to easily calculate the max capacity of an Accommodation in other words I need to calculate the capacity = persons + supplementary_bed of all units of that accommodation and find the max value.

I also need to filter all the accommodation with that value so, max_capacity >= n where n is a value submited by a form.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use django aggregation, how it works you can find in [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset)